# Steam stuck on extracting package

Tags: steam

I just did a format on my PC and am now currently re-installing steam. However, steam is taking very long to "Extracting Package". It has been 2 hours now and the window is still 'Responding' - i.e. it doesn't say not responding on task manager etc. but it is still "Extracting Package".

Is there a something I am missing here, I re-installed it after it gave me an error about some ".dll" file missing. And now it just hangs on this part of the installation.

Comment: Do you know which .dll file was missing? And have you tried restarting your computer and attempting the installation again (ie is this a problem that keeps occurring)?

Comment: "steamui.dll" - so I just uninstalled, deleted the installer and re-downloaded the installer from steam website. Then installed and now this. It has placed a desktop icon but if I click on it it gets stuck on "Installing Update" whilst the other one says "Extracting Package". Yes I have restarted my laptop and tried again.

Comment: I would try downloading the steamui.dll from a .dll website, and copying and replacing it into the steam folder. Try here https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/steamui_dll.html

Comment: If I get the error message about the ".dll" file again I will be sure to do this. at the moment though, I have a suspicious feeling that it could be a network issue?

Comment: It's possible, though I suspect that it is related to the .dll, see here https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/648814845404204770/

Comment: You could also try restarting your computer in safe mode, deleting all the steam files except AppData and the steam.exe, and then double clicking steam.exe to try to install the update. This is another fix that appears to be working to solve this issue. BTW if either of these work, I'm happy to post an answer for everyone else encountering the same problem

Comment: Yea, I read this thread earlier. Now both my instances have started saying "Installing Update". So I ran a diagnostics on hardware, drivers and internet connection. It seems for some reason steam is not connecting to the internet properly but my PC is on a decent line and can stream full HD without a buffer.

Comment: Okay I found the issue just got a call from a friend who knows more about this than me, he said sometimes on the start up of steam on a fresh computer can take a while and I just need to be patient, it is also because my RAM is only 4GIG DDR3 so with dreamweaver, photoshop, MySQL Workbench etc still open it is struggling. SO I have closed these now, seeing what happens.

Comment: Great, keep us posted, and if you resolve it yourself please post an answer explaining what you did. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks man. Sorted I am in steam, seems it was a memory issue as my CPU was at 98% and my memory at 100%. Time for a new laptop soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible issues and their fixes:

1. "steamui.dll missing" - Thanks to B. S. Morganstein; you can download the file at:  https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/steamui_dll.html 
   AND
   Read about the problem here: http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/648814845404204770
2. Low Memory (RAM) - Close all other applications (Foreground and Background) that may be taking up RAM or CPU. This will help the installation process go faster. Be patient as if you have low specs like mine; it can take a couple of hours.

Comment: No problem! You can also choose your own answer to close the question